# Passing recursively found files into cmdlet

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

I need to pass a bunch of files to a cmdlet (`Measure-CharacterFrequency` to be specific), but the files are scattered around in subdirectories. If I just do `"*.txt"` it will only get the files in the top directory. I also tried

```
Measure-CharacterFrequency (Get-ChildItem "*.ps1" -Recurse -Force |
    Select-Object FullName | Format-List)
```

but that didn't work either. How can I pass in all of the files?

Comment: From where did you get the `Measure-CharacterFrequency` cmdlet?

Comment: It's from [PowershellGallery.](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Measure-CharacterFrequency/1.0.0/DisplayScript)

Comment: Remove `| Format-List`. Do not use `*-Format` cmdlet unless your presenting output to a user.

Comment: Thank you very much Ansgar! That and removing Select-Object did the trick!